# i want to change value of a submit type button?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

i have code of a form.
Code for submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
```

After successfully saved this form, i want to change value of button to "Update".
I am using following code but it is not working.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
$("#submit").val("Update");
});
```

Comment: Works [Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Comment: $("#submit").click(function(){
$(this).val("Update");
}); Do you even have an idea about how many nodes are in the DOM ?

Comment: Your example works fine, can you be more specific about what's not working

Comment: @Siry .. After submitting the form i am on same page.

Comment: Are you aware by submiting form the page is reload?! Prevent default behaviour in some way then...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
$("#submit").val("Update");
});
```

In this code the #Submit should be unique in the DOM. There shouldn't be any other element in the DOM with id submit. If there exists such an element the code will show irregularity.
I suspect that there may be more than one id=submit. try below code.

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButtonOne" value="Save" />

$("#submitButtonOne").click(function(){
$("#submitButtonOne").val("Update");
});
```

**EDIT:**

If your button is rendering dynamically try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('click','#submitButtonOne',function(){

        $(this).val("Update");

    })


});
```

make sure that you have loaded jquery library.

Comment: still i am not able to find solution.

Comment: This is not likely an event delegation problem.

Comment: @AneeshMohan It works, but when page reloads after saving the data in database, value again changes to "Save".

Comment: @JitendraKhedar Then you have to use post it using AJAX instead of plain html post

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, when you press the submit button, you are leaving the page and then reloading it.

You need to prevent the default behavior of the form and use AJAX to save the form.

Let say `form` is your form.  You would do the following:

```
form.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...and then your AJAX call.
    // I won't go into the mechanics of AJAX,
    // as there is lots of documentation online.
    // Since you're using jQuery, I recommend http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.
    // Then, in your success function I would use your code:
    $.ajax({
        success: function () {
            $("#submit").val("Update");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  $(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(){

        $(this).val("Update");
       return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: This is halfway right. This will allow the OP to change the value of the submit button, but his form will not be saved!

Comment: This wont submit the form!